# TSQL Calculating running data based on name of Month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have data like this

```
mis       mnth            IPTV
------------------------------------
0         January         0.2026856
0         February        0.4860267
0         March           0.2650674
0         April           0.1904701
1         January         0.266809
1         February        0.310241
1         March           0.2083876
1         April           0.3401039
2         January         0.307787
2         February        0.5276488
2         March           0.3037852
2         April           0.1822988
3         January         0.8107423
3         February        0.2430134
3         March           0.1988006
3         April           0.2539602
```

I would like to add cumulative IPTV based on month. So "January"& "February" should look like this and also all the rest of the month exactly same way.

```
mis        mnth           IPTV
-------------------------------------------------------------------
0          January        0.2026856
0          February       0.4860267
1          January        0.2026856+ 0.266809
1          February       0.4860267+0.310241
2          January        0.2026856+ 0.266809+0.307787
2          February       0.4860267+0.310241+0.5276488
3          January        0.2026856+ 0.266809+0.307787+0.8107423 
2          February       0.4860267+0.310241+0.5276488+0.2430134
```

and so on for the rest of the months. Can someone please help?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you were looking for TheGameiswar answer or an actual running total

You may notice that I add a Month's table just to keep the sequence correct.

```
Declare @YourTable table (mis int,mnth varchar(25),IPTV decimal(18,9)) 
Insert Into @YourTable values (0,'January',0.2026856),(0,'February',0.4860267),(0,'March',0.2650674),(0,'April',  0.1904701),(1,'January',0.266809),(1,'February',0.310241),(1,'March',  0.2083876),(1,'April', 0.3401039),(2,'January',0.307787),(2,'February',0.5276488),(2,'March',0.3037852),(2,'April',0.1822988),(3,'January',0.8107423),(3,'February',0.2430134),(3,'March',0.1988006),(3,'April',0.2539602)

Declare @Months table (Seq int,MnthName varchar(25)) 
Insert into @Months values(1,'January'),(2,'February'),(3,'March'),(4,'April'),(5,'May'),(6,'June'),(7,'July'),(8,'August'),(9,'September'),(10,'October'),(11,'November'),(12,'December')

Select A.mis
      ,A.mnth
      ,IPTV = sum(B.IPTV) 
 From  @YourTable A
 Join  @YourTable B on (A.mnth=B.mnth and B.mis<=A.mis)
 Join  @Months    C on (A.mnth=C.MnthName)
 Group By C.Seq,A.mis,A.mnth
 Order By A.mis,C.Seq
```

Returns

```
mis mnth        IPTV
0   January     0.202685600
0   February    0.486026700
0   March       0.265067400
0   April       0.190470100
1   January     0.469494600
1   February    0.796267700
1   March       0.473455000
1   April       0.530574000
2   January     0.777281600
2   February    1.323916500
2   March       0.777240200
2   April       0.712872800
3   January     1.588023900
3   February    1.566929900
3   March       0.976040800
3   April       0.966833000
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help .

Answer (score 0):

Didn't tested though

```
  select mis,mnth,
    stuff((select '+' +cast(iptv as varchar(100))
    from table t2 
    where t1.id<=t2.id and t1.mnth=t2.mnth
    for xml path('')),1,1,'') as val
    from
    table t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @John Cappelletti, my query is listed below, basically this is a running-total scenario.

```
Declare @YourTable table (mis int,mnth varchar(25),IPTV decimal(18,9)) 
Insert Into @YourTable values (0,'January',0.2026856),(0,'February',0.4860267),(0,'March',0.2650674),(0,'April',  0.1904701),(1,'January',0.266809),(1,'February',0.310241),(1,'March',  0.2083876),(1,'April', 0.3401039),(2,'January',0.307787),(2,'February',0.5276488),(2,'March',0.3037852),(2,'April',0.1822988),(3,'January',0.8107423),(3,'February',0.2430134),(3,'March',0.1988006),(3,'April',0.2539602)

--below is the solution
select *,sum(iptv)over(partition by mnth order by mis) as Wanted
from @yourtable
```

Result is as below:

[image]

Comment: Even though I would love you use this and thank you for the solution I was getting error that led me to believe that I am using an older version of SQL.

Comment: This query could work since SQL Server 2005, what version you are using?